# link doesn't ask for confirmation with :confirm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, confirm

I'm trying to setup a link that deletes a database entry, and everything works as intended, it just doesn't ask for confirmation first. I think I've done everything right, I'm testing this in firefox on ubuntu.

```
<%= link_to "Delete", @post, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete?", :method => :delete %>
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Read the documentation carefully`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to):

> `:data` - This option can be used to add custom data attributes.

**Data attributes**

> `confirm: 'question?'` - This will allow the unobtrusive JavaScript driver to prompt with the question specified (in this case, the
>   resulting text would be question?. If the user accepts, the link is
>   processed normally, otherwise no action is taken.

Your `link_to` should be like this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", @post, data: { :confirm => "Question?", :method => :delete } %>
```

[`Look at this if you use a version before 4.0.2`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

Comment: You can be forgiven for getting it wrong though. Before rails 4 the confirm option was used exactly in the question - it's perfectly likely that there are examples out there that do it the rails 3 way.

Comment: @Shadwell thanks for your point, i know. OP doesn't specify version, i assume what Rails be last version.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right to assume the latest version. Just adding a footnote to your answer :)

Comment: yeh, what happened was I was using latest rails with a 2 year old tutorial. Thanks for linking the relevant documentation, favoriting for later.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this lines in your application.js file ?

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```